# How to merge two data sets with shared cases and variables without duplicating variables?

Tags: r, join, dplyr

Suppose I have the two following data sets:

```
library(tidyverse)

iris1 <- iris %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number(),
         Petal.Length = ifelse(id > 75, NA, Petal.Length),
         Petal.Width = ifelse(id > 75, NA, Petal.Width))

iris2 <- iris %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
  filter(id > 75) %>% 
  select(id, Petal.Length, Petal.Width)
```

Here, I've set `iris2` to be data that is missing from `iris1`. I would like to join the data in `iris2` back into `iris1`, using `id` as the key. I could use `dplyr::full_join` and join by `id`, but I would have duplicated the variables `Petal.Length` and `Petal.Width` when in fact I want the values in `iris2` integrated into their respective variables in `iris1`.

Is there a more elegant solution than doing the below? The example here is with 2 variables (`Petal.Length` and `Petal.Width`), but in my actual dataset this impacts over a hundred variables, and I'd have to think there's a better way than by manual labour.

```
left_join(iris1, iris2, by = "id") %>% 
  mutate(Petal.Length = ifelse(is.na(Petal.Length.x), Petal.Length.y, Petal.Length.x),
         Petal.Width = ifelse(is.na(Petal.Width.x), Petal.Width.y, Petal.Width.x)) %>% 
  select(-Petal.Length.x, -Petal.Length.y, -Petal.Width.x, -Petal.Width.y)
```

Comment: I am not clear on what you find unclear @philipxy. I'm very clearly providing a reproducible example, and I've written far more than that one sentence.

Comment: OK I finally figured out that the last code does what you want. Note though that despite all that text you don't give a clear specification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reduced your data set to 10 rows. I haven't thought this through but this could work.

Here are the steps - 1) added a dataframe identifier field `tablename` 2) did a union using `bind_rows` 3) grouped by `id` and got the ***first*** non-NA value for each column using `summarize_all()`. This means that you need to bind tables in order of preference.

```
iris1 <- head(iris, 10) %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number(),
         Petal.Length = ifelse(id > 7, NA, Petal.Length),
         Petal.Width = ifelse(id > 7, NA, Petal.Width),
         tablename = "table1"
         )

# A tibble: 10 x 7
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species    id tablename
          <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>   <int> <chr>    
 1         5.10        3.50         1.40       0.200 setosa      1 table1   
 2         4.90        3.00         1.40       0.200 setosa      2 table1   
 3         4.70        3.20         1.30       0.200 setosa      3 table1   
 4         4.60        3.10         1.50       0.200 setosa      4 table1   
 5         5.00        3.60         1.40       0.200 setosa      5 table1   
 6         5.40        3.90         1.70       0.400 setosa      6 table1   
 7         4.60        3.40         1.40       0.300 setosa      7 table1   
 8         5.00        3.40        NA         NA     setosa      8 table1   
 9         4.40        2.90        NA         NA     setosa      9 table1   
10         4.90        3.10        NA         NA     setosa     10 table1  

iris2 <- head(iris, 10) %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number(), tablename = "table2") %>% 
  filter(id > 7) %>% 
  select(id, Petal.Length, Petal.Width, tablename)

# A tibble: 3 x 4
     id Petal.Length Petal.Width tablename
  <int>        <dbl>       <dbl> <chr>    
1     8         1.50       0.200 table2   
2     9         1.40       0.200 table2   
3    10         1.50       0.100 table2

combined <- bind_rows(iris1, iris2) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarize_all(function(x) x[!is.na(x)][1])

# A tibble: 10 x 7
# Groups:   id [10]
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species    id tablename
          <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>   <int> <chr>    
 1         5.10        3.50         1.40       0.200 setosa      1 table1   
 2         4.90        3.00         1.40       0.200 setosa      2 table1   
 3         4.70        3.20         1.30       0.200 setosa      3 table1   
 4         4.60        3.10         1.50       0.200 setosa      4 table1   
 5         5.00        3.60         1.40       0.200 setosa      5 table1   
 6         5.40        3.90         1.70       0.400 setosa      6 table1   
 7         4.60        3.40         1.40       0.300 setosa      7 table1   
 8         5.00        3.40         1.50       0.200 setosa      8 table1   
 9         4.40        2.90         1.40       0.200 setosa      9 table1   
10         4.90        3.10         1.50       0.100 setosa     10 table1
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, Shree. I might not have been clear in my initial question, so I updated it. The issue is having to do `Petal.Length = Petal.Length[!is.na(Petal.Length)]` etc. within `mutate`. I have over 100 variables that I would need to apply this to.

Comment: But actually, if instead I run `mutate_all(function(x) x[!is.na(x)])` then it should work. Can you make the amendment, and I'll check it as the correct answer?

Comment: edited...although I would wait on marking this as correct. I have feeling there is a better solution for this.

Comment: changing to `summarize_all(function(x) x[!is.na(x)][1])` instead of `mutate_all`. Avoids the last filter and should be faster I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Another potential solution, but this assumes that there are no NA cases prior to the manipulation. Basically, join the two data files, turn them to long, remove the ".x" and ".y" from the variable names, and remove NA rows, and then spread the data back to its original shape:

```
iris1 %>% 
  left_join(iris2, by = "id") %>% 
  gather(key = key, value = value, -id) %>%  
  mutate(key = str_remove(key, "\\.[xy]$")) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(value)) %>% 
  spread(key = key, value = value)
```